# The best way to reach an email index to read mails using Text-to-speech

Tags: android, email, indexing, outlook, text-to-speech

Ok, I'M not an expert in Android as you see but I'm trying to create a simple app that let the user to press a button and start reading by voice the email that he received..
My problem is: I can't access the index of any email service, I looked around & tested Gmail API but the index isn't shown, and I heard about Outlook Dev for android but it seems v.2 is underdevelepment and finally WebView which made me think how would the code would recognise the actual text from the JavaScripts!

Is there something I missed or a real way  allows me to access the Gmail or outlook index and read the desired mail?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any API in Android allowing you to fetch the email content.

I would go an extra mile and create my own web service. This web service would fetch emails from provider using OAuth. Also, it would give an ability to handle email content, re-format things like phone numbers before it goes to TTS.